# Deleted partition didn't fix windows boot

Tags: windows, uninstall

Okay so I uninstalled Ubuntu. Deleted its partition and hit the wrong button before I fixed the windows boot loader. Now I am stuck at the grub terminal on boot. Is there any way to load windows from it or fix my problem?

**Edit** This is where I am stuck:

```
                GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu-1.2

  Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
  lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists 
  possible device or file completions.

GRUB>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should restorce your boot records, using the method described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/). So, run the system restore option of a Windows installation media, then get a command prompt, and write this in it:

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

That should fix it.

Comment: I can't get access to boot menu justs stuck at the grub terminal

Comment: I understand, but you do not need GRUB for this *at all*. Just a Windows installer DVD or USB drive, and you should boot on that.

Comment: Added picture that is what I get on boot

Comment: You have to boot from the windows DVD.

Comment: I understand that but how I am just stuck in that terminal

Comment: At the BIOS, press the key to select your boot device. The exact F* key depends on the BIOS or vendor, so I don't know which one it is.

Comment: What I didn't know hp wants you to hit the escape key first

Comment: Oh, in a HP F9 is what you want :)

Comment: No first escape then f9 after a menu comes up